# Linking new Google Apps Marketplace application with an existing Chrome Web Store application

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have an existing Chrome Web Store listing with many active users (Over 10k).
I have created a new Google Apps Marketplace application that support OAuth2.0.

The existing listing already have a manifest.json file.
It has an 'apps' definition as it's an installable chrome app:

```
"app": {
  "urls": ["http://www.mysite.com/landing_page"],
  "launch": {
    "web_url": "http://www.mysite.com/chrome_login"
  },
}
```

As instructed in the google apps marketplace publishing guide I've added the following information to the manifest file:

```
  "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "<app_id>"
```

Unfortunately after doing this my application disappears from the chrome web store (Although I can see it in the new Google Apps Marketplace list).

I need a way to have both the Chrome Web Store and the Apps Marketplace link to the **same listing** (so they will share the user count).
I've seen some applications, e.g 'MindMeister', that have achieved this so I know that it is possible.

Could someone please advise me on how to configure this correctly?

Comment: Great question. Very interested to see what the reply is. It seems that the Google Apps SDK is an ever-changing, un-documented, mysterious platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After communicating this issue with Google's support the answer is that this is currently **impossible** to have a single listing published both for CWS and Google Apps Marketplace simultaneously.

Their best practice suggests to have two separate listings, one for each.